# How to use USB interface of R305 Fingerprint Module instead of UART

Tags: image, module, usb, fingerprint

### What I have done so far:

I am currently working on [R305 Fingerprint Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0paFj.jpg). I have used this module and some other fingerprint modules like R301T and FPM10A for different projects. But this time I have a new requirement. I want to **download** fingerprint **image** (bitmap) **from sensor to my PC**. So I used **[pyFingerprint](https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint)**, a Python library to interact with R305 fingerprint module using **UART protocol**.

This library provides function to download fingerprint image to PC and it is working for me. I can easily download fingerprint image ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQl6Y.jpg)) from sensor to my PC.

### What is the Issue:

Now problem is UART (TTL) communication is very slow when it comes to transfer fingerprint image to PC, a lot of bits, and max baudrate for UART of R305 module is **115200** bps. So it takes about **4 to 5 seconds** to transfer fingerprint image from sensor to my computer (e.g. on Desktop). It is way too slow for real-time applications where you want fingerprint image within no time.

### What I want to do:

I want to interface this R305 fingerprint module **directly** with **USB interface** without any USB to TTL converter attached on UART (Tx, Rx) of the module. So that I can download/transfer fingerprint image at faster transfer speed (using USB). I read the documentation of this Module and it says that this **module supports two types of communication protocols (USB and UART)**. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcNVj.jpg) . So I solder one end of a simple USB cable to USB port of the module (VCC D- D+ GND) and plug the USB cable's other end to PC. Now the **module is showing as CD-ROM** in PC. In Device Manager it is showing name as "Finger Module". Now How can I interface with the module??? I have searched a  lot and there is no Software available for this USB interface. Please help me about this..

Comment: No one available to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the required .Net SDK** to control this R305 Fingerprint Sensor (for all 30X series Sensors) **using USB protocol**. I searched a lot and also sent email to Chines company that build these sensors and asked for this SDK but they did not reply. By chance, fortunately I found the SDK link on Dropbox. 
So If anyone want the SDK please Download it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pznvlzx8qx5nfr3/AABpzhSyjqH0qWNYgMvxqAA9a?dl=0

It contains many files/projects, it also has SynDemo software source code, Arduino code, SDK for Linux platform and a lot of other stuff.. This is really helpful.